# How Salable Quantity Works and how we can manage?

Tags: magento2.3, quantity, out-of-stock, salable

On the Category page, a product shows "Add to Cart" button and after clicking on it it redirect on product detail page with **"Out of stock"** message.

As checked and found that this product has 2 qty and stock is "In stock" while **"Salable Qty" is 0** due to which it shows "out of stock" on detail page.

**First Question:-** Why qty is showing 2 and "Salable Qty" 0,how can we manage "Salable Qty".

**Second Question:-** when i modify the product qty to 20 then "Salable Qty" becomes 18 and when modify to 100 it becomes 98 means it always minus two why?

Please find attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the Category page, a product shows "Add to Cart" button and after clicking on it it redirect on product detail page with "Out of stock" message.

As checked and found that this product has 2 qty and stock is "In stock" while "Salable Qty" is 0 due to which it shows "out of stock" on detail page.

Answer (score 0):

On the Category page, a product shows "Add to Cart" button and after clicking on it it redirect on product detail page with "Out of stock" message.

As checked and found that this product has 2 qty and stock is "In stock" while "Salable Qty" is 0 due to which it shows "out of stock" on detail page.